# Screenshot tool extension not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Instead of the default Ubuntu 22.04 screenshot feature, I prefer the screenshot tool extension.

[image]

Systray image

[image]

But the extension is not working on Ubuntu 22.04, it's showing an error.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue. I fixed it by simply running sudo apt install gnome-screenshot and installing the extension. Works well again on 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (at present) the old Screenshot tool will not work on the snap version of FF.

In order to make this work as before it is necessary to remove the Firefox snap and replace it with the APT version to obtain the old functionality.

The instructions to remove the snap version of FF and replace it with the APT version are contained [in this guide](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) published by OMG!UBUNTU! and is available elsewhere on AU [see this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22).

After replacing the snap with the APT version, there is a further step to follow to make it work as you require in your question.

Open a terminal and run `sudo apt install gnome-screen-shot`. This will complete the process.

This is the result on 22.04 (screenshot captured using these instructions).

[image]

Comment: Firefox snap might prevent the installation of the GNOME extension, but it should not have anything to do with how the extension works. The question is probably about a different issue.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it seems to be the case unfortunately. I tried it on 22.04 having already replaced the FF snap with the APT version and it didn't work until the final step was taken in terminal proof of which is in my graphic of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

and save the change. This will enable the Xorg display manager.

Then either

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Or just reboot the system.